# React+mobx not render on initial page loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I tried to dive into React+mobx but met a problem. I have store which fetch data from server and after fetching is ended fetched data have to be represented on page. Bug is on initial loading - no data renders after fetching (fetched data already loaded which shows in Network tab in console). 
But if I try to go to this page again from menu - data renders on page.

For understanding a problem I've prepared gitHub repo with fetching dummy data

[Test repo](https://github.com/kimonniez/mobx_bug_test)

For reproducing bug just `clone` repo. And `npm i` and `npm start`

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is a good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the issue (and learnt from it :) ).

Your store should look like this

```js
export class DashboardStore extends BaseStore {

  @observable stat = []; // <-- your response is an array, so start with array

  @observable regInfo = [];
  @observable regInfoReady = false;

  fetchStat = async () => {
    const statResponse = await this.callApi('fetchStat');
    runInAction(() => { //async methods can't be marked as action, cause they are async
      this.stat = statResponse;
    });
  };
}
```

The surprising part for me was the fact that if `render` method is defined as **property with arrow function** won't re-render on observable change.

So just change the `render` to a method of a class.

```js
// Dashboard/index.jsx

...
render() {
    const { stat, regInfo, regInfoReady } = this.props.dashboardStore;

    return (
      <div>
        <Row gutter={16} style={{ padding: '30px 0px 30px 0px' }}>
          <Col span={8}>
            <Card title="Titles" bordered={false}>
              {stat.length && stat.map(row => (
                <div key={row.id}>
                  {row.title}
                </div>
              ))}
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
...
```

Comment: WOW!!! Thanks a lot) Two days of googling gave nothing!
P.S. My real response is object and here I just forgot to change stat var to array :)